# Quicksort debugging

Tags: c, quicksort

I'm trying to debug a version of quicksort that has intentionally had a vital line removed, and I'm having trouble understanding it.

The broken version:

```
void quicksort(char *v [], int n)
{
     int i, last;
     if (n <= 1)                         /* nothing to do */
         return;
     last = 0;
     for (i = 1; i < n; i++)         /* partition */
           if (strcmp(v[i],v[0]) < 0)
              swap(v,++last, i);
     swap(v, 0, last);                 /* restore pivot */
     quicksort(v,last);               /* recursively sort each part. */
     quicksort(v+last-1, n-last-1);
}
```

The correct version:

```
void quicksort(char *v [], int n)
{
     int i, last;
     if (n <= 1)                         /* nothing to do */
         return;
     swap(v,0,rand() % n);       /* move pivot element to v[0] */
     last = 0;
     for (i = 1; i < n; i++)         /* partition */
           if (strcmp(v[i],v[0]) < 0)
               swap(v,++last, i);
     assert((last >= 0) && (last < n));
     swap(v, 0, last);                 /* restore pivot */
     quicksort(v,last);               /* recursively sort each part. */
     quicksort(v+last-1, n-last-1);
}
```

As you can see, the first version doesn't include the first call to swap(). When it's run with a plaintext it, it throws a segfault.

Comment: What is your question, though?

Comment: Why the first call to swap is required for the function to run correctly. I think that it may force the second call to quicksort to move past the bounds of the array v, but I'm not sure why. I also don't know why you can add an integer to an array.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your quicksorts are wrong.  This line:

```
quicksort(v+last-1, n-last-1);
```

Should be:

```
quicksort(v+last+1, n-last-1);
```

I fail to see why the one with the `rand()` is any better than the other one, though.